# Is Javamail API specific to Java-EE?

Tags: discussion, documentation, move-examples

I created a topic "Send Mail with Javamail API" under the Java Language. It got [approved by 4 persons](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/114431?filter-tags=java). Some days later I noticed that my created topic is no longer in the Java Language. I searched for some time and found it under the `java-ee` new topic named "Tha Javamail API". I believe that Javamail API is not specific to J2EE, so I created the topic under Java Language. Why this topic has been moved to Java-EE?

Moreover I did not get any notification of topic migration. Do you not think the owner of the topic should receive a notification about the migration of topic?

Comment: "This topic duplicates a topic in the JavaEE tag. And since JavaMail is a part of Java EE and not a part og Java SE, these examples belong there. Please move them and merge them." from https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/114470

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#JDK

Comment: JavaMail is part of Java EE, but just like other Java EE spec implementations, they can **also** be used outside of Java EE. Also, documentation topics don't have owners.

Comment: Got it, then it should be there

Comment: what about the 2nd element I think the owner of the post should get a notification of migration of the topic?

Comment: As I said, you don't really own a topic or a post; but yes a notification would be nice.

Comment: Owner means the primary contributor.